# Does the Chromecast audio require 5GHz Wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, audio, chromecast

When Googling for the requirements of the Chromecast Audio, I get different results. Can anyone confirm if 5 GHz Wifi is required, or that it works with both 2.4 GHz *and* 5 GHz?

From https://support.google.com/chromecast/answer/6279377?hl=en:

> Connectivity/Network: Wi-Fi 802.11 b/g/n/ac (2.4GHz/5Ghz)

From https://support.google.com/chromecast/table/6207416?hl=en&rd=2:

> In order to set up your Chromecast, make sure have access to a 2.4 GHz (for Chromecast (1st gen) devices) or 5 GHz network (for Chromecast and Chromecast Audio).

Comment: The second result should be interpreted as `2.4Ghz network for 1st Gen Chromecast` and `2.4Ghz or 5Ghz network for 2nd Gen Chromecast and Chromecast Audio`.